# C# - Exempt Null Cells in formatting

Tags: c#, datagridview, decimalformat, cell-formatting

I am new to the c# environment. I tried formatting a `datagridview` column to 2 decimal places using:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#,###.00";
```

This code works if all cells of the column are not null. But when one cell of the column have null value, it returns an error "'System.NullReferenceException'". How can I exempt null cells from being formatted to 2 decimal places?

Comment: The error you mean is System.FormatException?

Comment: As per this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f9x2790s(v=vs.100).aspx), you should be able to make use of the `dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue` which should enable your to over the error. eg. `dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue='NA'`.  Please give it shot...